# Multithreaded solution of a problem taking more time than single threaded, how to increase the performance?

Tags: java

Problem - **Converting input string into a series of weights.**
Character weights are 1 to 26 from a to z.
A uniform string consists of a single character repeated zero or more times.
For example, ccc and a are uniform strings, but bcb and cd are not.

Given a string 's', let 'U' be the set of weights for all possible uniform contiguous substrings of string 's'. There will be 'n' queries to answer where each query consists of a single integer.
Create a return array where for each query, the value is 'Yes' if query[i] is contained in 'U'. Otherwise, append 'No'.

Main Prog :

```
private static  Map<Character, Integer> freqMap;
private static  List<Integer> weights = new ArrayList<>();

freqMap = getFreqMap(input);
Object[] keys = freqMap.keySet().toArray();

TestThreadPoolExecutor.initThreadPool(10);
ExecutorService threadPoolMgr = TestThreadPoolExecutor.getThreadPoolMgr();
NewProbRunnable prog = new NewProbRunnable();
for(Object key : keys) {
    threadPoolMgr.execute(prog.new MyTask((Character) key));
}
threadPoolMgr.shutdown();
threadPoolMgr.awaitTermination(24L, TimeUnit.HOURS);
System.out.println("All thread tasks over");
```

MyTask.run method processes the key from freqMap and adds to the list of weights.

```
private void processFreqMapEntry(Object key) {
        int wt = 0;
        Integer val = freqMap.get(key);
        while (val > 0){
            wt = (charList.indexOf(key)+1)* val;
            synchronized (weights) {
                 weights.add(wt);
            }
            --val;
        }
    }
```

When the program execution on Mac is timed, the threaded version is taking 20 ms and single-thread version takes bit lesser ~ 17.

1. Why is multithreading taking more time?
2. How can I improve the speed of the program? Having the attribute 'weights' as volatile instead of being modified in synch block did not make any diff.

Comment: Measurements in the order of 20ms are not useful, because typically the OS switches tasks every 10ms. Try measuring with much larger data sets, so that your test takes at least 1 second total. Also, threading for the sake of threading isn't helpful, as task switching includes a significant penalty.

Comment: 1) There is no reason to do `freqMap.keySet().toArray()`. The `for` loop works with `keySet()`. 2) Even better would be iterating over `entrySet()`, so you have key and value in the first place, so there’s no need to perform a hash lookup for the job. 3) Declaring `val` as `int` instead of `Integer` removes the boxing overhead. 4) You haven’t shown what `charList` is, but `indexOf` sounds suspiciously like a linear search. 5) `ArrayList` is not the best choice for adding concurrently. 6) A “divide and conquer” approach is better than creating a new job for every key. 7) 17 ms is not much time.

Comment: @Holger Can you explain 'divide and conquer' approach?                                         With 35K entries, time taken by both single and multi ~ 850-855 ms.                     charList is List<Character> from a-z

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm) is quite exhaustive. When you have a random access source, you can simply use the range [0, size] as starting point, recursively splitting into subranges from start to middle and from middle to end, until you have enough subtasks for each worker thread. The worker threads then process their assigned ranges sequentially. Since your source is a map, you might use the built-in facility instead, call `entrySet().spliterator()` and use the `Spliterator`’s `trySplit()` method for subdividing into subtasks.